# Basic string concatenation in C++ not outputting properly

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am having trouble with concatenation in C++ with Visual Studio. I have tried different variations of the cout but to no avail.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter last name and age\n";
string first_name;
string last_name;
string l2 = "Mr. " + last_name;
int age;
cin >> last_name >> age; 
cout << "Hello, "  << l2 << age << "\n";
}
```

Can anyone help explain what is going on here that prevents it from displaying "Hello, Mr. last_name age"? The current output just displays "Hello, Mr. 22".

Answer (score 1):

```
string last_name;
```

This declares a `last_name`, a string. It's not initialized to anything, so this is an empty string. After that, the next statement gets executed:

```
string l2 = "Mr. " + last_name;
```

This declares `l2`, and it's initialized by combining "Mr. " with whatever's in `last_name`. There's nothing in `last_name`, it is an empty string. So, `l2` contains "Mr. " and nothing more, and that's the output you see.

Later on:

```
 cin >> last_name >> age;
```

This does read `last_name` from `std::cin`. Which makes absolutely no difference, whatsoever, any more. Just because this statement ends up initializing `last_name`, it has no effect, whatsoever, on whatever `last_name` was previously used for. It was empty when it was used to initialize `l2`, and just because it's now initialized to something else it doesn't mean that `l2` gets reinitialized this way. C++ does not work this way. Statements in C++ get executed in order, one statement at a time, and once they're executed they're ancient history.